# Xpath to get only first text tag and ignore break tag before it

Tags: html, xpath

I checked for similar questions and but I couldn't find answer for mine.

I need to collect the text value comes inside a h1 tag, as per the example value "text1", which comes in 3 different situation. I am sharing all 3 html codes below:

First Case:

```
<h1 class="h1">
    text1
    <br> 
    <span>text2</span>
</h1>
```

Second Case:

```
<h1 class="h1">
    <span>text1</span>
</h1>
```

Third Case:

```
<h1 class="h1">
    <br> 
    text1
    <span>text2</span>
</h1>
```

I used the xpath

> //h1[@class="h1"]/text()[1]|//h1[@class="h1"]/span[1]

But it select the `<br>` tag in the third case. Is there anyway, I can ignore the break tag and get the `text1` value in all 3 cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//h1/descendant-or-self::text()[normalize-space()][1]
```

It selects the first descending text node of `h1` that is not empty or contains only whitespace.